# Page Not Found 404 Error is Coming when pages are refreshed..................i deployed my app on git hub

Tags: reactjs, github, routes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFA2O.png)

while deploying my Reactjs app on GitHub I am facing page refresh problem, however, on localhost app is working fine, pages are refreshed and get the component.
it seems that this is a project build problem.
I need a solution for it that why this problem is coming on project build.
Also, I did not install my packages using --save flag, I am confused about that flag options.

Comment: pleas check this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#notes-on-client-side-routing

Comment: if you are using react router, you need to go with the 'HashRouter' on github pages